# Как объединить две модели в одной форме? Связь один ко многим. Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, валидация, форма

Хочется собрать опрос + варианты ответов в одной форме с применением JQuery и Drag'n'Drop для сортировки.
Набросок на изображении.

Как правильно реализовать подобное, чтобы работала валидация обеих моделей (вопрос + ответы)? Сначала создать опрос, а потом прикреплять к нему по одному варианту ответов? Или же можно как то грамотно всё объединить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для удобства вопрос и ответы групируем в массивы

```
<input type="text" name="question[text]" class="form-control">
//
<div class="col">
   <input name="answers[1][text]" type="text" class="form-control" value="Yes">
</div>
<div class="col">
   <input name="answers[1][position]" type="text" class="form-control" value="0">
</div>
```

2. Вы делаете валидацию не модели, а данных формы. Форма одна, значит и валидацию можно сделать одну

```
$data = $request->validate([
           'question.text' => 'required|unique:question|min:3',
           'answers.*.text' => 'required|min:1',
           'answers.*.position' => 'integer|distinct'
]);
```

3. После валидации сохраняем вопрос и ответы для него.

```
$question = Question::create($data['question']);
////
$question->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);
```